# Blood become denser when you are dying of deshidration?

Tags: human-biology

Blood become denser when you are dying of deshidration? I mean, when you are dying of deshidration does your body extract water from blood to survie more time?

Comment: Your reasoning is a bit off. You need "water" *in your blood* to survive. When you don't have enough water in your blood, you become thirsty. If you can't drink, water is extracted from your cells to survive. When there's not enough, you die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an abstract describing an experiment where they kept horses away from water.

[Carlson GP, Rumbaugh GE, Harrold D. Am J Vet Res. 1979 Jul;40(7):982-5.
Physiologic alterations in the horse produced by food and water deprivation during periods of high environmental temperatures.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/507502)

> Eight normal horses were held without access to food or water for 72
>   hours during a period of high environmental temperatures. During this
>   period, the horses had an average weight loss of 51.6 kg (10.7% of
>   body weight). Highly significant (P less than 0.001) decreases in
>   extracellular fluid volume (18.6 L) and plasma volume (5 L) were
>   observed during this period as compared with base-line values. Plasma
>   protein, sodium, chloride, and osmolality progressively increased in
>   response to the dehydration, whereas packed cell volume, plasma
>   potassium, calcium, magnesium, and phosphate were not significantly
>   altered. The dehydration and clinicopathologic alterations produced
>   were similar to those observed in other species in which the principal
>   problem was a water deficit. After the end of the experimental
>   dehydration period, the horses replaced 62% of the weight loss during
>   a 1-hour period with access to water only.

As the horses became dehydrated they took water from both plasma (the fluid component of blood) and extracellular spaces (tissue water).  "Packed cell volume" refers to red cells.  Red cells and cells in general do not readily give up their intracellular water.  They defend it with osmotically active solutes.  If cells gave up their water the packed cell volume would decrease - like a cup of grapes turning into raisins.

Increase in "Plasma protein, sodium, chloride, and osmolality" reflects to non-water components of blood, which increased in concentration as water was lost.  Like a soup cooking down and getting richer.

This all works the same with humans.

Comment: "As the horses became dehydrated they took water from both plasma..." I'm not understanding; how did 'they' 'take water' from plasma? Where did it go to?

Comment: @anongoodnurse: To meet their physiologic needs for water.  Ultimately out in urine, sweat, breath and feces.

Comment: Urine production stops. Sweat isn't a major problem Breathing is. Feces? They'll stay there and get hard as rocks. I'm not sure where you're getting your info.

Comment: @anongoodnurse - if there is any confusion, a fine question for this stack would be "Why do organisms like horses need water?"

Comment: I know why animals need water. I'm pointing out that your answer sounds like water in plasma is less important that urine, sweat, breathing and feces. Plasma osmolality increases because there is no external source of water.

Answer (score 1):

Yes blood becomes denser on dehydration (water dilutes the blood, if there's no water in blood it becomes dense). No, body does not draw water from the blood. When you are dehydrated, blood is the first source to be depleted. Then blood pulls water from cells (there are various hormones acting on kidneys and blood vessels trying to preserve the remaining amount of water by increased reabsorption, decreased excretion and vasoconstriction to comparitively useless parts of the body) and on continued dehydration, heart is not getting enough blood to pump as liver is sacrificing all its blood to the brain and cells are being depleted of water and are dried up. So blood is dense and there is not enough amount to reach the brain and brain cells don't get enough glucose (ischemia) and build up of urea and BUN in blood on the other side. Brain Cells switch the metabolism as they try to keep the cells alive only to produce radical oxygen species as by-products which in turn destroys the cells. And hence. Death. Eventually.

Comment: It will be very useful if you'll add a few references to your answer.

Comment: Umm. You can refer to physiology of brain cells and pathophysiology of Ischemic brain diseases, endocrinology and haematology chapters dealing with excessive excretion of water and body's compensatory mechanisms. I don't want to quote any book titles. You can just refer to any good pathology book. My answer is merely a gist of one of the possibilities of the process and it is related to severe dehydration or medical conditions that are irresponsive despite drinking loads of water. It is more complex than my above explanation. There are so many other pathophysiology of dehydration.